# Plotly Dash bootstrap components, columns and rows do not order as the basic examples

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I've been having some problems getting a dash app to layout properly, so I took one of the basic examples and tested, and it's giving me a very different result to the dash website.

```
import dash
from dash import dcc, html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

main_content = html.Div(
    [
        dbc.Row(dbc.Col(html.Div("A single, half-width column"), width=12)),
        dbc.Row(
            dbc.Col(html.Div("An automatically sized column"), width="auto")
        ),
        dbc.Row(
            [
                dbc.Col(html.Div("One of three columns"), width=3),
                dbc.Col(html.Div("One of three columns")),
                dbc.Col(html.Div("One of three columns"), width=3),
            ]
        ),
    ]
)

app.layout = main_content

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.run_server(debug=True,)
```

the result is this, no columns:

[image]

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Put the link to the example in the documentation to see what the output should be.

Comment: Add `external_stylesheets` as `external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.LUX]` and it should work.